# Scheduling server reboot

Tags: centos, scheduled-task, schedule

How can I schedule an automatic reboot of my server with CentOS via terminal or via plesk every 12 hours?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following to root's crontab:

```
0 0,12 * * * /sbin/init 6
```

But honestly, why on God's green earth would you want to reboot every 12 hours?

Comment: init 6 is the same of reboot?

Comment: also reboot or shutdown -r would work as well in that cron job, but i echo @ErikA's point, why do you want to reboot every 12 hours

Comment: I have a problem on my server and i can't fix them in this week so i need to reboot it every 12 hour to save it from crash. How can I add this line? I run this command crontab -e and I get a list of all the scheduled process, how can I add the line that erikA suggest to me? Thanks

Comment: @paul - there are many questions on SF about adding cron jobs. Just search for one and you'll find the information you're looking for.

Comment: I run crontab -e and I simple add the line 0 0,12 * * * /sbin/init 6 then I save the file. Is everything ok? thanks

Comment: @paul Yes, that should do it. Now just wait until midnight (in whatever timezone you server is set to) and see if it reboots.

Comment: if I want to restart the server every 10 hours the command must be 0 0,10 * * * /sbin/init 6 right? thanks

Comment: @paul No. See: http://mostlygeek.com/tech-reference/crontab-reference/